# How to use TextAppearanceSpan

Tags: android, textview

i can make smaller last 2 number but i want them to show top as shown below picture.

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("13.500,27");        

WordtoSpan.setSpan( new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 12, null, null), WordtoSpan.length()-2, WordtoSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);    
TV.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Thanks talha

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

You can use `SuperscriptSpan()`

```
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString("13.500,27");        
WordtoSpan.setSpan( new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 17, null, null), WordtoSpan.length()-2, WordtoSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);  
WordtoSpan.setSpan( new SuperscriptSpan(), WordtoSpan.length()-2, WordtoSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Increase font size to see the effect

[image]

---

Try this
I don't find any other way, but to append the superscript text to original spannalbe string

Apply Spans what ever you want for the SpannableStringBuilder

```
  SpannableStringBuilder builder=new SpannableStringBuilder("13.500,");
  builder.append(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>27</sup>"))
```

**Edit 2**

If you create custom span like below, it align supertext to top absolutely. But if you use default SuperscriptSpan ,it couldnt make the text alignt to top.

```
public class SuperscriptSpan2 extends MetricAffectingSpan implements
            ParcelableSpan {
        public SuperscriptSpan2() {
        }

    public int getSpanTypeId() {
        return TextUtils.CAP_MODE_CHARACTERS;
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.baselineShift += (int) (tp.ascent() / 1.25);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.baselineShift += (int) (tp.ascent() / 1.25);
    }
}
```